# IOS/Objective-C: UIPickerView not displaying

Tags: uipickerview

My picker view is not displaying.  I just see an empty box where the picker view should be.  I have done all the steps shown below. My question is, is this a complete list or am I missing something?  Unless, I am missing something, I will just delete and redo from scratch but thought it would be good to enumerate all steps and get confirmation that they should be sufficient:

1. Drag uipickerview to storyboard.
2. Set delegate and datasource in storyboard by ctrl dragging pickerview to file owner and selecting both.
3. Ctrl drag from uipickerview to interface/.h file to create outlet for picker view as follows:
   `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;`

4.Set delegate in viewdidload although this may be redundant to storyboard with `pickerView.delegate = self;`

5.subscribe to uipickerviewprotocol in interface file as follows:

```
 @interface myVC : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

6.Include delegate methods as follows in implementation file and specify array to display

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
      return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return 10;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSArray* cities = @[@"Oslo", @"Berlin", @"Cupertino", @"Palo Alto", @"Menlo Park", @"Mountain View", @"San Jose", @"Los Altos", @"Woodside", @"Berlin", @"Berlin"];
            return cities[row];
}
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
  _selectedCity= ([cities objectAtIndex:row]);
    }
```

**Edit:**

7. Check constraints in storyboard to make sure that the contents of the pickerview are not being pushed out of view.  As pointed out by GeneCode in comments, this turned out to be issue.

Is anything else needed or should above be adequate?

Comment: I tried your code it works fine. I think, your pickerview positioning is off. Did you set the constraints properly?

Comment: That was it.  The constraints were evidently pushing the contents of the pickerview off the screen.  Am adding a 7th step above.  Thanks!